# Invalid encoding on shared folder mounted via fstab, but not in GUI

Tags: samba, fstab, cifs, character-set

Mounting the folder via Network in Nemo shows all filename correctly, but when doing via Fstab with this code...

```
//servername/sharedfolder /media/mountedfolder cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

... I have no spanish characters ([in example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T81J.png)).

**1st NOTE**: the folder I try to mount is shared by a router with a USB port, and I think this is relevant because...

**2nd NOTE**: ... I test to mount with the same code another folder shared by a laptop with linux too, and everything's fine.

UPDATE: found a exactly duplicated of my problem [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-cifs/msg10028.html), apparently this its not easy to solve.

Comment: If memo is like nautilus it mounts using gvfs , this will be listed if you run mount, you can then see if its applying other mount options by comparing the line in the mount output when mounted via each method.

Comment: @Amias mounting via command line don't return me so much info. Also, I found [this](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/unicode.html#id2669921) and tested with different iocharset and codepage values but give me the same result.

Comment: if you run mount on the command line with no options it returns a list of mounted filesystem and their options, this data comes from the /etc/mtab file.

Comment: @Amias ahh, ok ok. I get the default options used by gvfs-mount but I still get bad encoded characters. According to [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-cifs/msg10028.html) (if I understood well) the router is the problem.

Comment: file sharing from routers is never a great idea , they always miss important options like code pages but worse there is rarely sensible load separation in the code so a heavy file access can cause your internet connection to drop the link by starving the routers processor for long enough to make the other end think its gone away.  I've seen this happen with folders with lots of files in as well.